# Conflicting Succession Law Conditions

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm looking to change the succession law from Gavelkind to Primogeniture.

However there appear to be conflicting conditions.

1. Title is not a Viceroyalty.
2. Holder, Any Held Title, Is a Viceroyalty.

[image]

How can I achieve these conditions?

Comment: Apparently you need to hold a viceroyalty tilte, different from the title your trying change the succession law for.  Note that you don't need to meet this requirement. It's just "one of these [that] must be true". You meet the second of these in the list but it's cut off at the bottom.

Comment: @RossRidge O, I hadnt noticed the UI issue, is there anyway to see the full list of conditions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second "One of these must be true:" is a parallel condition to the holding a viceroyalty condition. I'm guessing this is a mod, as usually the conditions wouldn't just be blank like that, but basically you'd be able to change the succession law because you fulfilled the second condition (currently blank) of the "One of these must be true". The reason you can't change it right now is actually just that second condition of "You must have ruled for at least ten years"

Comment: I'll wait 10 years and give it a go then, as a side no mods being used apart from anything in the DLC bundle.

Comment: That worked by the way,

Comment: Glad it worked out! That's odd that Paradox left that blank, unless it's just that for whatever reason you couldn't see the other conditions. Who knows?